# Speed up ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have two issues with the following code. (1) It executes too slowly. If I use "Speed" instead of "Quality" for PerformanceGoal, I get the speed but an undesirable delay in proper rendering of the contour. Perhaps the calculation of the expression to be contoured is the cause of the slowness. If so, can that be accelerated? (2) How can I make the z-axis vertical. Note its appearance with some jaggies.

```
Manipulate[  
    ContourPlot3D[
    {z == 10*x*y*Exp[-x - y], z == k}, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 3}, 
    ContourStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.9]},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick], AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick], 
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue], ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
    ViewPoint -> {-4, -8, 4}, ImageSize -> 2 {420, 370}],
    {{k, 0.5, Text@Style["k", Italic, FontSize -> 18]}, 0, 1.35, 0.01, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nature of the function you've provided makes `ContourPlot3D` an overkill. Use `Plot3D` and set the `ViewPoint -> 100 {-4, -8, 4}` a little further to make the `z` axis straight.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot3D[10*x*y*Exp[-x - y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Red], 
      Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Directive[Blue, Opacity[.5]]], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue]], 
                  Dynamic@Polygon[{{0, 0, k}, {0, 6, k}, {6, 6, k}, {6, 0, k}}]}], 
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> 100 {-4, -8, 4}, 
      ImageSize -> {420, 370}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick]], 
 {{k, 0.5, Text@Style["k", 18]}, 0, 1.35, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Nasser gives good standard `ControlActive` approach. But that by definition looses quality during motion. I just would like to share a trick that avoids that. Most of the time is spent on rendering your bell shape. But it is static. Plane moves but it is simple, so it should not all the time trigger recomputing of static bell shape. You can separate motion of plane from bells shape with Dynamic. This will allow you to move without loss of quality during motion.

```
Manipulate[

 Show[

  ContourPlot3D[
   z == 10*x*y*Exp[-x - y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 3}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],

  Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Directive[Blue, Opacity[.5]]], 
    EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue]], 
    Dynamic@Polygon[{{0, 0, k}, {0, 6, k}, {6, 6, k}, {6, 0, k}}]}],

  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick], ViewPoint -> {-4, -8, 4}, 
  ImageSize -> {420, 370}]

 , {{k, 0.5, Text@Style["k", Italic, FontSize -> 18]}, 0, 1.35, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: @Vitally Kaurov - Motion is too jerky. See Kuba's use of Plot3D instead of ContourPlot3D

Comment: @Stephen i've seen it - it is a nice idea working in this case. but that's not the point of my post. in some situation you will not be able to replace ContourPlot3D with Plot3D.

Comment: @Vitally Kaurov - Since my surface has the form f(x,y)-z=0, there is no point in using ContourPlot3D which must calculate the points to plot by some implicit method.

Comment: @Stephen I know that ;) I was trying to share a general useful trick. And as you can see even Kuba adopted it for his code - in addition to his idea. Because it often makes things better.

Comment: @Stephen yep, the question title still states about seeding up the contour plot :)

Answer (score 8):

You can speed things up by using `ControlActive` on some of the options which slows down things. Like this

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[{z == 10*x*y*Exp[-x - y], z == k}, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}, {z, 0, 3},
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.9]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None,
  PerformanceGoal -> ControlActive["Speed", "Quality"],
  Contours -> ControlActive[3, 10],
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[3, 10],
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick],
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick],
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue],
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
  ViewPoint -> {-4, -8, 4},
  ImageSize -> {420, 370}],

 {{k, 0.5, Text@Style["k", Italic, FontSize -> 18]}, 0, 1.35, 0.01, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled", ContinuousAction -> True}
 ]
```

If you also change `ContinuousAction -> True` to `False` that will speed it up more.

[image]

see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html

The idea is to wrap those options which can slow down things using `ControlActive` with values that are low as first argument, which will cause the plot to update fast as the slider is moving, but when the slider stops, the second argument is used giving the better final looking plot (but slower to render)

Comment: Your first answer was better; the edited version produces too crude an approximation to the level curves. Kuba used Plot3D instead of ContourPlot3D.